# How do I get the Firebase user object and use it in different React components?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase and trying to get the current signed in user. I check to see if a user is signed in using `componentDidMount` and if a user is signed in, I try and update my state.

Now, even though I am getting a Firebase user object in my console, the state is never updating. It also doesn't update when signing a user up for the first time using the `toggleSignIn` method.

All of this is being done in my `App.js file`. I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about trying to get the currently signed-in user and update the state accordingly so I can use the user object in other components and get things like the users `photoURL`, `displayName`, etc.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  **getInitialState:** function () {
    // Set initial state of user to null
    return {
      user : null
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    // Checks to see if a user is signed in and sets state to the user object.
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        **this.setState({
          user: user
        });**
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
  },
  toggleSignIn: function () {
    if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      // Create an instance of the Google provider object
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      // Sign in with popup.
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // Get signed-in user info
        **this.setState({ 
            user: result.user
        });**
        // ...
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
      });
    } else {
      // Sign user out
      firebase.auth().signOut();
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <main  className="app-content">
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```